My autogenstudio userproxy excute code is successful but without any output
I have created an autonomous workflow with user proxy agent and my assistant agent.
For my assistant agent I provide a skill, and in the past it works. However recently my output from my user proxy agent is blank, even in the console the execution is successful. I don't get it.
exitcode: 0 (execution successful)
Code output:

In my skill (function) it returns the output I am looking for.
Besides, the final executed code did have print() at the end of the execution. However my user proxy shows Output which resulting my assistant agent saying that nothing is produced. I really don't understand why.
Below is my sample skill just for testing purpose:
def add_two_numbers(number1, number2):
    print(number1 + number2)
    a=input() ## this is just to stop for a min in Python so I can view the result
    return number1 + number2

below is the console output:
userproxy1 (to test_sum_up_agent):

2024-07-25 13:50:25.319sum up 2,4
 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO     | autogenstudio.web.app:message_handler:38 - ** Processing Agent Message on Queue: Active Connections: [*] **
2024-07-25 13:50:25.334 | INFO     | autogenstudio.web.app:message_handler:45 - Sending message to connection_id: *. Connection ID: *

test_sum_up_agent (to userproxy1):

To sum up the numbers 2 and 4, you can use the `add_two_numbers` function from the `skills.py` file. Here is the Python code to do this:

```python
from skills import add_two_numbers

number1 = 2
number2 = 4

total = add_two_numbers(number1, number2)
print(total)
```

When you run this code, it will print the sum of the two numbers, which is 6.2024-07-25 13:50:31.096

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
>>>>>>>> EXECUTING CODE BLOCK (inferred language is python)...
INFO     | autogenstudio.web.app:message_handler:38 - ** Processing Agent Message on Queue: Active Connections: ['*'] **
2024-07-25 13:50:31.102 | INFO     | autogenstudio.web.app:message_handler:45 - Sending message to connection_id: *. Connection ID: *
userproxy1 (to test_sum_up_agent):

2024-07-25 13:50:48.344exitcode: 0 (execution succeeded)
**Code output:**
 |
INFO    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | autogenstudio.web.app:message_handler:38 - ** Processing Agent Message on Queue: Active Connections: ['*'] **
2024-07-25 13:50:48.371 | INFO     | autogenstudio.web.app:message_handler:45 - Sending message to connection_id: *. Connection ID: *
test_sum_up_agent (to userproxy1):
2024-07-25 13:50:57.181
The task was to sum up the numbers 2 and 4. The Python code provided used the `add_two_numbers` function from the `skills.py` file to perform this task. The code was executed successfully and the sum of the numbers, which is 6, was printed. However, due to a technical issue, the output was not displayed. It was suggested to verify the result by running the code in a Python environment. The sum of the numbers 2 and 4 is confirmed to be 6.

TERMINATE |


I don't know, I'm still trying to figure out skills myself.
I don't know if you're using a container, but some of the things I've had to do are
1.) tell my agent to run/execute the code locally (or in docker I guess)
2.) you need to manage your return/summary message.  There's an options for last, LLM, or none (or something like that).  Give your agent specific instructions to summarize or return the value in the final response, and make sure you've picked last in the agent setup
try looking at the default setup, if you don't have that, or you have a lot of noise run autogenstudio ui --appdir = C:\temp\autogen or any other folder
3.) this doesn't look to be relevant since it's running the code, but tell your agent about the skill.  "Use the add_two_numbers skill to solve the problems..."
Your output shows that the system knows the answer is 6
My other suggestions would be to remove the print and input commands, I'm sure you added them for debugging purposes, but... well that's what I got.
